# SurfaceView camera preview squared: avoid image distortion

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I have the sequent scenario: a surfaceview of square shape (on top of acvitity) and a green view below (that i will fill on future with other views). Now i would that preview of camera inside surfaceView it's squared, because i need to take squared picture, but preview is distorted (maybe because i gave preview dimension not squared). I show you code.

How i calculate dimension of square at runtime and assign dimension to green view

```
surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
surfaceViewDimension = dpWidth;
int borderHeight = dpHeight - dpWidth;

View bottomBorder = findViewById(R.id.bottom_border);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, borderHeight);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

bottomBorder.setLayoutParams(params);

bottomBorder.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

this is how i set camera options:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);
    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);

    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setPictureSize(dpWidth, dpWidth);
    params.setRotation(90);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}

public Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters params, int width,
        int height) {

    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        Log.d("size: ", size.width + ":" + size.height);
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

how could i change my code for obtain a squared preview without image distortion (saved picture is not distorced, only preview)?